# PyCharm cannot install packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, windows-10

Short description: two computers in the same network, in the new one only those python scripts work that use native packages.

I have Pycharm in my old computer and it has worked fine. Now I got a new computer, installed the most recent version of Python and Pycharm, then opened one of my old projects. Both the old and the new computer are in the same network and the project is on a shared folder. So I did the following:

1. File - Open - selected the project. Got a message that there is no interpreter
2. Add local interpreter - selected the latest Python 311 exe. So location of the venv is the same as in the old computer (because it's a network folder) but Base interpreter is pointing to the C drive of my new computer.
3. PyCharm creates a virtual environment and the code runs fine.
4. I select another project which uses imported packages such as pandas. Again, same steps as above, add local interpreter. Venv is created.
5. I go to File - Setting - Project and see that pip, setuptools and wheel are listed as Packages. If I double click one of these, I can re-install and get a note that installation is succesful, so nothing seems to be wrong in the connection (after all, both the old and the new computer are in the same network.
6. I click the plus sign to add a new one, search pandas. Installation fails. Same thing if I try e.g. numpy.

Error message has lots of retrying, then "could not find the version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none", "not matching distribution found for pandas" (pip etc. have the latest versions).

After few hours of googling for solutions, I have tried the following:

1. Complety uninstall and reinstall python and PyCharm. Checked that PATH was included in the installation.
2. Tried launching pip command from shell
3. Changed http proxy to auto-detect
4. Typed 'import pandas' in PyCharm, then used the dropdown in the yellow bulb but there is no install option
5. Started a new project in the new computer, tried to install pandas

All failed. I'm surprised that changing computers is this difficult. Please let me know if there are other options than staying in the old computer...

Comment: I had similar problem with installing packages in a new computer. And I resolved it by installing some C++ libraries, but I can't remember their versions. Try to install all the necessary Visual Build Tools.

Comment: I checked and all the Microsoft Visual C++ packages are the same in both installations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use venv in the network, please use SSH interpreter. Pycharm supports this method. Shared folders are not a recommended usage, For pycharm, it will consider this as a local file. If the file map is not downloaded locally, it will make an error.
Another way is to reinstall the project environment on the new computer through `requirement.txt`. Reasonable use of `requirements.txt` can effectively avoid many project bugs caused by environment migration or different dependent versions.  Before installing some scientific module such as pandas, it is recommended to install visual studio build tools, such as gcc ...

Comment: I tried the following. First, to rule out the network folders, I copied the network project folders to my C drive. I opened the easy project that uses no imported packages. All good as before. With the project using imported packages, the error is the same. I tried both using the existing interpreter in the project folder and the new interpreter that comes with the new installation. Of course, this is expected because even if I start a fresh project, import will not work.
If I go for the sync python requirements in my old computer, the outcome is that the file is empty.

Comment: It seems that the environment is more complex than imagined and described. Is it possible to supplement complete operation video or GIF?

Answer (score 0):

This took a while but here is what happened. Package installation did not work in project settings. Neither did it work when you select Python Packages tab at the bottom of the screen. The only thing that worked was to select the Terminal tab and manually install (pip install) there. We use a trusted repository but for other users, the easier package installation methods work. Not sure why they do not for me but at least there is this manual workaround.